# Tracking Call Histories

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, phone

I am looking to track the following information for each call made:

- Attempt Number
- Status of Call (No Answer, Busy, etc)
- Date and Time of call
- Who made the call
- If possible, the length of the call

Has any developer created a way to track calls and the result of that call in CiviCRM?  If yes, how did you do it?

Or is this something that CiviCRM can do?  If yes, where can I find this information?

Thank you,

LAE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is something CiviCRM can do.

You could create [custom fields](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/master/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/) to track this information and record each (attempted) call as an [activity](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/master/organising-your-data/activities/).  Using the activity method, you could even assign a follow up call to a staff member/volunteer if you wanted.  You could use a [Profile](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/master/organising-your-data/profiles/) to simplify the entry of the information.  If you are using Drupal as your CMS, you could create a streamlined [webform that integrates with Civi](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration) and have a simpler and more specific interface for entry of the call data.